# How to calculate the time complexity of a Java program?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

How can I calculate the time complexity of this program? Is there a more efficient solution?

```
public class MinJumpstoEnd {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int[] a = {1, 3, 5, 8, 9, 2, 6, 7, 6, 8, 9};
        //i is used for array elements & c to count jumps

        int i =0,c =0;
        int j = a[0];
        
        while(a.length-i > j) {
            if(a[i]==0) {
                System.out.println("Cant Reach");
            }

            i += j;
            c+=1;

            j = a[i]-1;
            System.out.println("j:"+j);
        }
        System.out.println("Jumps : "+c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worst case is that it'll step on every element in the array, so _O(n)_.

Comment: Are negative inputs allowed? Are there any other requirements to the input?
When O is hard to determin otherwise O(n).

Comment: What happens for the input `1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1`? `j` will become `0` and `i` will remain at `1`. And the loop will never stop!?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: @Marlon No Neg Inputs Are Not Allowed

Comment: @luk2302 No It Will Jump Atleast Once Each Time

Answer (score 0):

In the worst case your i has to traverse the whole array, and hence it would be O(n).
It might happen that it might skip few elements in between while traversing but still it would be a linear function.

Comment: I don't think this answers OP's question (at least not in detail). They are asking how to calculate it, and not which complexity measurements apply to which types of algorithms. Though that helps, it may not be obvious to them how to connect the dots.